# Sort cluster numbers from kmeans in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sorting, k-means

The `idx` output argument of `kmeans(X,k)` contains unique values `1:k` but in arbitrary order; e.g. for data with clusters that are already contiguously indexed (i.e. `kmeans` is used to identify gaps/boundaries), the unique values don't reflect the order of clusters in the data. How can each value of the `idx` output be renumbered such that the unique values appear in ascending order, i.e. `unique(idx,'stable') == unique(idx)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The renumbering can be performed by using the [`ic` output argument](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#output_argument_ic) of `unique`:

```
% Find k clusters
idx = kmeans(X,k);

% Renumber idx for unique values in ascending order 
[~,~,ic] = unique(idx,'stable');
```

`ic` contains the indices for deriving `unique`'s input from its default output argument, `C`, i.e. `idx == C(ic)`. Normally `C` is sorted, but by supplying `'stable'` for the `setOrder` input argument, `C` contains the unique values in `idx` in order of appearance, so each unique value from `idx` will be renumbered in a way that leaves `ic` sorted.

The idea for using `ic` alone is based on a [post](http://stupidmatlabhacks-blog.tumblr.com/post/17884423775/removing-gaps-in-a-sequence-of-integers) by *Stupid Matlab Hacks* on Tumblr to map the unique values of an input vector `v` to `1:length(unique(v))`.